# Edit a txt file in classpath permanently

Tags: java

I need to permanently edit a txt file in my project classpath. If I run my project in Eclipse the change is saved correctly and the edited file is inside the directory bin, but if I generate the Jar and try to edit the file the program doesn't work

this is the way I edit the file:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_PATH).getFile(), true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        br.newLine();
        br.write("StartGusto");
```

[This is my classpath and the file i want to edit is GustiUTF.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biZ7h.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi Silvano, welcome to StackOverflow. If you'd post the error you're getting it would be easier to help you.

Comment: URL.getFile() *does not* return a valid file name.  It returns the path portion of a URL, which is not the same thing.  Regardless, all resources in the classpath should be considered read-only;  imagine what will happen when you run from a .jar file.  Treat your resource as a read-only default, and keep a writable version somewhere under the user’s home directory that acts as an override.